# Removing popUpMenus from CNF (Common Navigator Framework) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rpc, eclipse-3.4

I have been partially successful at removing almost all the popUp menus from the Commons Navigator Framework simply by configuring the `plugin.xml` file.
There are 2 menus that refuse to go:

- `group.edit` and
- `group.reorganize`.

My `plugin.xml` config looks like this:

```xml
<extension
          point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
       <viewer
             viewerId="org.eclipse.ui.example.navigator.view">
             <popupMenu allowsPlatformContributions="false">
                <insertionPoint
                    name="group.edit" />

                <insertionPoint
                    name="group.reorganize" />
             </popupMenu>
       </viewer>
       <viewerContentBinding
             viewerId="org.eclipse.ui.thermo.navigator.view">
          <includes>
             <contentExtension
                   pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent"/>
          </includes>
       </viewerContentBinding> 
</extension>
```

Setting the `allowsPlatformContribution` to false DOES stop contributions to be added to the context menu *except* for `group.edit` and `group.reorganize`... this is starting to look like a bug to me.

The obvious solution is to remove the insertion points from my `<popUpMenu>` but without them the application throws an exception:

```
Throwable: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Group not found: group.edit

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Group not found: group.edit
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ContributionManager.addToGroup(ContributionManager.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ContributionManager.appendToGroup(ContributionManager.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.EditActionGroup.fillContextMenu(EditActionGroup.java:74)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.EditActionProvider.fillContextMenu(EditActionProvider.java:50)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService.addCommonActionProviderMenu(NavigatorActionService.java:205)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService.fillContextMenu(NavigatorActionService.java:172)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager.fillContextMenu(CommonNavigatorManager.java:258)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$4.menuAboutToShow(CommonNavigatorManager.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.fireAboutToShow(MenuManager.java:335)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.handleAboutToShow(MenuManager.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.access$1(MenuManager.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager$2.menuShown(MenuManager.java:485)
```

It throws  the same exception for the reorganize group.

Comment: Add recent article on CNF which may be of interest (see my completed answer)

Comment: Could you check if you still have the error with a RCP based on eclipse3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I succeeded in removing the "group.edit" actions (Copy/Paste) and I've done it that way, using the Common Navigator extension points :

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
      <viewerActionBinding
            viewerId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer">
         <includes>
            <actionExtension
                  pattern="my.app.client.actions.MyAppEditActionExtension">
            </actionExtension>
         </includes>
      </viewerActionBinding>    
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
      <actionProvider
            class="my.app.client.workshop.MyPasteActionProvider"
            id="my.app.client.actions.MyAppEditActionExtension"
            overrides="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.actions.EditActions"
            priority="highest">
         <enablement>
         <!-- A hack to allways be enabled -->
         <not>
            <systemTest
                  property="MyApp"
                  value="WONT-EVER-BE-SET">
            </systemTest>
         </not>
         </enablement>
     </actionProvider>
   </extension>
```

And, with addition of "org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources" in my plugin dependencies, I implemented "MyPasteActionProvider" like this :

```
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IContributionItem;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IMenuManager;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.EditActionProvider;

/**
 * Create the Edit actions (Cut/Copy/Paste) 
 * and register then globally in the workbench using EditActionProvider.
 * <p/>
 * Then, removes the Copy/Paste contributions in the pop-up menu.
 */
public class MyPasteActionProvider extends EditActionProvider {
   public void fillContextMenu(IMenuManager menu) { super.fillContextMenu(menu);
   // remove Copy/Paste contributions
   IContributionItem copyItemRemoved = menu.remove("org.eclipse.ui.CopyAction");
   IContributionItem pasteItemRemoved = menu.remove("org.eclipse.ui.PasteAction");
   }
}
```

Well, that's a "discouraged access" but I was getting myself discouraged ;-)
JM.D

Answer (score 1):

This [thread suggests](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg32982.html) to remove the things that are causing the menu items to appear in the first place:

They are probably in action sets, so if you can identify the action set that's causing the offensive contribution, you can do something like this in your `WorkbenchAdvisor`:

```
    ActionSetRegistry reg = WorkbenchPlugin.getDefault()
            .getActionSetRegistry();


    IActionSetDescriptor[] actionSets = reg.getActionSets();
    String[] removeActionSets = new String[] {
        "org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.actionSet",
        "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.annotationNavigation",
       "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.convertLineDelimitersTo",
          "org.eclipse.ui.WorkingSetActionSet",
        "org.eclipse.update.ui.softwareUpdates", };


    for (int i = 0; i < actionSets.length; i++)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < removeActionSets.length; j++)
        {
            if (removeActionSets[j].equals(actionSets[i].getId()))
                found = true;
        }


        if (!found)
            continue;
        IExtension ext = actionSets[i].getConfigurationElement()
                .getDeclaringExtension();
        reg.removeExtension(ext, new Object[] { actionSets[i] });
    }
```

The closest bug I have found is the [145233: Make more obvious way to specify input (for RCP apps)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=145233), with a [similar hack](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=145233#c23).
Bug [143430 (CommonNavigator requires initialInput to be Adaptable)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=143430) is a more general one, and would indicate that then CNF has been improved with eclipse3.5 (Galileo).
So do you also have this issue with 3.5 and a custom CNF class?

---

As mentioned in the article "**[Eclipse CNF: Navigator Content Extensions](http://www.techjava.de/topics/2009/08/eclipse-common-navigator-framework-2/)**", CNF has evolved with eclipse3.5, and this article seems to have some tree with true custom contextual menu entries.

[image]

Comment: I tried this suggestion but it did not work. It makes me think that the reason is that it was deprecated a while ago. Maybe there is a new way of doing this with the newer api?

Comment: That may be the case, but what version of eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should be using the [Command Framework](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Platform_Command_Framework)  with any recent version of Eclipse (3.3 or higher), this replaces the mechanism for providing popup menus in the Common Navigator.